# iPhone Popup dialog hidden behind UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiactionsheet

I have a UIActionSheet that displays various buttons, one of which posts a tweet to Twitter. To do so, the app has to request permission to access the user's Twitter account that they set in the settings on iOS 5. The problem is this popup gets hidden behind the UIActionSheet, like so:

[screenshot http://dl.dropbox.com/u/51070/actionsheet.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/51070/actionsheet.png)

How can I get it to show above the action sheet? I've also tried dismissing the action sheet through dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated before calling the tweet function, but this problem still occurred.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you present action sheet? I thought it is dismissed automatically after any button pressed.

Comment: You're right, it does, but apparently I needed to add a delay before calling the tweet selector so the action sheet would have more time to dismiss itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling your tweet method like this:

```
 [self performSelector:@selector(myTweetMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

This should give the action sheet enough time to dismiss before invoking the tweet code.